# Tensorflow: Convert to model to TFLite format

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently having an issue converting tensorflow .pb model to TFlite format. I'm currently following the instruction on [Google CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2) The error says

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/bin/tflite_convert", line 5, in 
>       from tensorflow.lite.python.tflite_convert import main ImportError: No module named lite.python.tflite_convert

I'm using the command provided by Google

> tflite_convert \   --graph_def_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
>   --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \   --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \   --output_format=TFLITE \   --input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \   --input_array=input \   --output_array=final_result \   --inference_type=FLOAT \
>   --input_data_type=FLOAT

Is there any other code alternative to convert a model to TFlite format?
By the way, I'm upgraded my Tensorflow to 1.12.0 since 1.7, 1.8 and 1.9 returning the same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please refer sample code to convert .pb to tflite

```
import tensorflow as tf
pb_file = 'model.pb'
tflite_file = 'model.tflite'

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(pb_file, ['ImageTensor'], ['SemanticPredictions'], 
                                                      input_shapes={"ImageTensor":[1,523,523,3]}) # [1,H,W,C]


converter.inference_input_type=tf.uint8
converter.quantized_input_stats = {'ImageTensor': (145, 164)}  # (mean, stddev)

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model) 

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

files.download(tflite_file)
```